# SQL select statement

Tags: sql, select

I have an SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE username = 'bbb' 
    OR username = 'aaa' 
    OR username = 'ddd' 
    OR username = 'ccc'
```

In the table ddd has the biggest id than ccc than bbb than aaa.

Now when it returns the results it always sorts them by the id like:aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd. 
But i want them to remain in the same order i entered them like: bbb, aaa, ddd, ccc.

Can someone help me with a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL the order of retrieval is unspecified unless you ask for it with `ORDER BY`. If you want to keep the order you entered them then add a progressive `ROW_NUMBER` column and ask for a sort on that.

Comment: Certain databases have default orderings that you shouldn't rely on, but which are nonetheless present.  For example, a MySQL InnoDB table will return results ordered by ascending `PRIMARY KEY` by default.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from users where username='bbb' 
UNION
select * from users where username='aaa' 
UNION
select * from users where username='ddd' 
UNION 
select * from users where username='ccc'
```

Despite the fact that this query may achieve what you wish, as user 6502 stated, the order is still unspecified in this query, and therefore you can't safely depend on it to be returned as such across different implementations.

As another side note, if your *strange* sort order didn't matter, you should just use a WHERE IN clause:

```
select * from users where username in ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc')
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is a curious perversion.

Comment: i get "The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable." if i use union

Comment: I can't help you directly with that without seeing your schema. One of your fields is of type text, and you need to cast it to varchar.

Comment: Or, you are using a field of type text when it should really be varchar (username sounds like a varchar field to me, not a text one!)

Comment: it's varchar... for a simple select statement without the union it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an "id" column in the users table (with ddd having the "biggest id"), then you can do something like this:

```
select * from users where username in ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')
order by id;
```

ETA:  If the id column is in another table, then you'll have to perform a join to get the correct ids.